# How to add link title in Typo3

Tags: hyperlink, typo3, title

I'm actually absolutely new to Typo3 and need some help. I've got a site (6.1.5) with a main menu - but none of the links has a title:

```
<li>
<a href="sub/page1.html">page1</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="sub/page2.html">page2</a>
</li>
```

In the backend I can use "Page Title", but nothing appears in the frontend.

Thanks in advance!

Dublay

Answer (score 1):

We need to know more to help! 
Have a look at the template section in the BE Menu. Look if you find there an Object named TMENU. Is so, this would be your solution:

```
ATagParams = title="{field:abstract // field:subtitle // field:title}"
ATagParams.insertData = 1
```

Like that first the abstract is taken, if empty the subtitle, if empty the title.

Have a look here: http://www.serious-cool.de/webdesign/typo3/dynamische-linktitel-im-menue/

I you cannot find anything alike, your template is propably rendered with fluid. That means you have somewhere in your system a navigation.html file you need to find and modify.

Since Typo3 is very dynamically developing there are more then one possibility to render a menu....

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick reply. Looks like, it's "Fluid LA 1". According to your answer I have to search for a file named navigation.html? With FTP oder in Backend?

Comment: Usually an extension provides it and usually an integrator copys that and stores it in "some other place". Have a look in the "TS Object browser" and you'll find the path to the root html file. From there you navigate to the navigation partial.

Comment: Found this: [linkConfig]
[target] =  # typolink-configuration for links / urls #parameter and additionalParams are set by extension
[ATagParams] = rel="nofollow"    <- right place?

Comment: no. You need to look for a path, given in the typoscript. This path will point to the template files. I am sorry, but without rudementary knowledge of typo3, I won't be able to help further.

Comment: Thanks so far. I know it's very difficult to help, but I've found this: "tt_content.menu.20.1.1.NO.ATagTitle.field ="  <- is this helpfull?

Comment: nope, you have to look at the path below ``page.10.``.